# Get duplicate file list by computing their MD5

Tags: c#, linq, md5

I have a array which contains a files path, I want to make a list a those file which are duplicate on the basis of their MD5. I calculate their MD5 like this:

```
private void calcMD5(Array files)  //Array contains a path of all files
{
    int i=0;
    string[] md5_val = new string[files.Length];
    foreach (string file_name in files)
    {
        using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
        {
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(file_name))
            {
                md5_val[i] = BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(stream)).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
                i += 1;
            }
        }
    }                
}
```

From above I able to calculate their MD5 but how to get only list of those files which are duplicate. If there is any other way to do same please let me know, and also I am new to Linq

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`1.` Rewrite your `calcMD5` function to take in a *single* file path and *return* the MD5.
 `2.` Store your file names in a `string[]` or `List<string>`, not an untyped array, if possible.
 `3.` Use the following LINQ to get groups of files with the same hash:

```
var groupsOfFilesWithSameHash = files
  // or files.Cast<string>() if you're stuck with an Array
   .GroupBy(f => calcMD5(f))
   .Where(g => g.Count() > 1);
```

`4.` You can get to the groups with nested `foreach` loops, for example:

```
foreach(var group in groupsOfFilesWithSameHash)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Shared MD5: " + g.Key);
    foreach (var file in group)
        Console.WriteLine("    " + file);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // returns a list of file names, which have duplicate MD5 hashes
        var duplicates = CalcDuplicates(new[] {"Hello.txt", "World.txt"});
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> CalcDuplicates(IEnumerable<string> fileNames)
    {
        return fileNames.GroupBy(CalcMd5OfFile)
                        .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                        // skip SelectMany() if you'd like the duplicates grouped by their hashes as group key
                        .SelectMany(g => g);
    }

    private static string CalcMd5OfFile(string path)
    {
        // I took your implementation - I don't know if there are better ones
        using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
        {
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
            {
                return BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(stream)).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var duplicates = md5_val.GroupBy(x => x).Where(x => x.Count() > 1).Select(x => x.Key);
```

That will give you a list of hashes that are duplicated within the array.

To get names instead of hashes as well:

```
var duplicates = md5_val.Select((x,i) => new Tuple<string, int>(x, i))
                        .GroupBy(x => x.Item1)
                        .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
                        .SelectMany(x => files[x.Item2].ToList());
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think he wants a list of the duplicated filenames, not the duplicated hashes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning an array of all the files MD5 hashes, do it this way instead:

- Have a single 'calculateFileHash()' method.
- Create an array of filenames to test for.
- Do this:

  var dupes = Filenames.GroupBy(fn => calculateFileHash(fn)).Where(gr => gr.Count > 1);

This will return an array of groups, each group being an enumerable containing the filenames with identical content to each other.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void calcMD5(String[] filePathes)  //Array contains a path of all files
    {
        Dictionary<String, String> hashToFilePathes = new Dictionary<String, String>();
        foreach (string file_name in filePathes)
        {
            using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
            {
                using (var stream = File.OpenRead(file_name))
                {
                    //This will get you dictionary where key is md5hash and value is filepath
                    hashToFilePathes.Add(BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(stream)).Replace("-", "").ToLower(), file_name);
                }
            }
        }
        // Here will be all duplicates
        List<String> listOfDuplicates = hashToFilePathes.GroupBy(e => e.Key).Where(e => e.Count() > 1).SelectMany(e=>e).Select(e => e.Value).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: This will way will work fastly and looks to much nice. After you can use `listOfDuplicates` as you want.

Comment: `.Select(e => e.First().Value)` causes to return one duplicate of each group of duplicates. I assume the filenames aren't duplicates, just their hashes. So in case there are three duplicates in one group, the information it returns is quite useless. I'd recommend `.SelectMany(e => e).Select(e => e.Value)` or leave them grouped entirely.

Comment: That is the way, but I dont think that it will look better or work faster. I'd recommend to use my first way.

Comment: acessing first element in array(which is in memory) is quick operation and there is no need to optimize it.

Comment: What do you mean with "look better"? If you'd like to get rid of all duplicates but one, your implementation definately lacks of information. In case there is more than one duplicate in a group.

Comment: Sorry, yeap now I understand you, you are right. I missed your first idea. Edited my answer